# Greenplum loader issue with Informatica CDC

Tags: informatica, greenplum

We use Informatica CDC to capture change data (near real time) from ERP source system. Our target is Greenplum DB. At Informatica session we use GP loader to load into target.

**Problem**:

As we fetch Near Real Time(NRT) data from ERP, we receive multiple records for same primary key if they have multiple updates.

Sample data:

```
PK | Non-PK  | Flag
--------------------
 1 | School  | U
 1 | College | U
```

Here for PK '1' we receive two records flagged as update. In that case in target we need to reflect the latest update i.e., 'College'.

But while using GP loader only the first updates are reflected in the target tables irrespective of any number of updates happened at source.

Please help me solve this issue

Comment: What if you only pass the latest record to target?

Comment: No other option than adding modification timestamp to the data and choosing the record with the max timestamp for each primary key